# getting the wrong POST value because of div show / hide

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

in my code i'm showing drop down select field list base on user school choice. for example - 
if user choose 'School of Economics' from drop down list, i'm showing in another drop down list just the relevant lanes (based on a mysql query).

to do this i have 5 div's, on for etch school:

```
<div id='a'>
<span><label>Lane</label></span>
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT lane_name FROM lane WHERE `lane_school_id` = 1 ORDER BY `lane_name` ASC";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        echo "<select name='lane_name'>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['lane_name'] ."'>" . $row['lane_name'] ."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";

?>
</div>

<div id='b'>
<span><label>Lane</label></span>
<?php

        $sql = "SELECT lane_name FROM lane WHERE `lane_school_id` = 2 ORDER BY `lane_name` ASC";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        echo "<select name='lane_name'>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['lane_name'] ."'>" . $row['lane_name'] ."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";

?>
</div>
```

i have a listener to show just the right 'lane' div when user chooses school and hide all other 'lane' div's:

```
        $(document).bind('pageinit', '#indexPage',  function(){
            $("#a").show();
            $("#b").hide();
            $("#c").hide();
            $("#d").hide();
            $("#e").hide();


            //this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of School field changes
            $("#school").change(function () {
                toggleFieldsA();
                toggleFieldsB();
                toggleFieldsC();
                toggleFieldsD();
                toggleFieldsE();
            });

        });

        function toggleFieldsA() {
            if ($("#school").val() == 'School of Economics'){
                $("#a").show();

            }
            else
                $("#a").hide();   
        }

        function toggleFieldsB() {
            if ($("#school").val() == 'School of Computer Science')
                $("#b").show();         
            else
                $("#b").hide();
         }
```

the problem: when user submit the form, i get the wrong 'lane_name' from POST array. i'm getting the last school selected lane value (that is hidden from the user) and not the user selected lane name , plz help

Comment: No surprises, you have  2 or more elements with the same name, and expects PHP to know which one you have used? That's why is that identifier... change them to unique names

Comment: Obviously, because `name` should be unique in a form. Besides, there's a lot wrong with your code: using deprecated `mysql_*` functions,  not using brackets, not caching your selectors, don't using CSS for showing/hidding them (initially and later on), not using proper variable/id names, …

Comment: i'm just learning so the code isn't good, i know.., if i will change the 'name's to unique values i will get 2 'lane name's in the POST - 1 that the user choose and one that was hidden but selected (the last one). how will i know what is the right value?

Comment: i've changed to unique 'lane name's and now i get all five div's default selected lane's when i really need just the one the the user selected (the div that wasn't hide): post: Array ( [school_name] => School of Economics [lane_name_a] => Economics and Management [lane_name_b] => BA in Computer Science [lane_name_c] => Behavioral Sciences [lane_name_d] => Government and Politics [lane_name_e] => aaaa [year] => 0 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give each `<select>` element a unique name, otherwise the last element with a particular name will be the only one you can access. PHP has no way of determining which of the 5 `lane_name` you are referring to.

To figure out what option set was selected you could make the first option blank: `<option value=""></option>`. You can add some logic to reset to the blank option when you hide/show the DIVs so only one of the lane_names will have any data in it.

The mysql_* is depreciated as of PHP 5.5.0. You should consider switching to [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).